# kerasを用いた学習用プログラムをGoogle Colaboratory で使いたい

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

スパイダーでまわしているプログラムをGoogleColaboraturyで使おうと思ったのですが、エラーがでてしまいます。

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
data = []
data1 = []
data2 = []
target = []
kairi = []
jyousyou = []
maxlen = 60
day1 = []
day2 = []
day3 = []
owarine = []
・
・
・
・
・

'''
モデル設定
'''
n_in = len(X[0][0])  
n_hidden = 100
n_out = len(Y[0])  
def weight_variable(shape, name=None):
return np.random.normal(scale=.01, size=shape)
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(n_hidden,
                    kernel_initializer="random_uniform",
                    input_shape=(maxlen, n_in)))
model.add(Dense(n_hidden, kernel_initializer="random_uniform"))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(n_out, kernel_initializer="random_uniform"))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
optimizer = Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
              optimizer=optimizer)


'''
モデル学習
'''
epochs = 500
batch_size = 1000
model.fit(X_train, Y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          validation_split = 0.25)

'''
学習はここまで
'''
```

これのmodel.fitの部分のようです。
エラーメッセージは以下です。

UnimplementedError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
173           batch_size=batch_size,
174           epochs=epochs,
--> 175           validation_split = 0.25)

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

以下で試したところ、Google colab(ランタイムタイプ：GPU, Python version 3.6.9, Keras version 2.4.3)で動かすことができました。
以下のXとYのサイズは適当においてしまったのですが、正しいでしょうか？もし正しければ、私の環境では動いたので、開発環境によるものかもしれないと思いました。

```
'''
モデル設定
'''

'''
※ 動作確認のため、以下2行 追加
'''
X = np.random.random([700,60,200])
Y = np.random.random([700,100])

n_in = len(X[0][0])  
n_hidden = 100
n_out = len(Y[0])  
def weight_variable(shape, name=None):
  return np.random.normal(scale=.01, size=shape)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(n_hidden,
                    kernel_initializer="random_uniform",
                    input_shape=(maxlen, n_in)))
model.add(Dense(n_hidden, kernel_initializer="random_uniform"))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(n_out, kernel_initializer="random_uniform"))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
optimizer = Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
              optimizer=optimizer)

'''
※ 動作確認のため、以下2行 追加
'''
X_train = np.random.random([700,60,200])
Y_train = np.random.random([700,100])

'''
モデル学習
'''
epochs = 500
batch_size = 1000
model.fit(X_train, Y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          validation_split = 0.25)
```